# Removed node modules and now getting 'Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/RuleSet'' error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, package.json, laravel-mix, vue-loader

I have a Vue app in a PHP project using Laravel mix.

My app was fine but I just recently deleted my node modules and package lock file.

After running `npm install` again, I am now getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/RuleSet'

when I try to run `npm run watch` or `npm run production`.

Comment: Try `npm i` first

Comment: I have ^ .   "After running npm install again, I am now getting Error...."

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're missing webpack from your package.json, but it was previously installed.  Clearing out your node_modules would also remove it.

To confirm, do "npm install webpack" in the root of your project and see if this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the Webpack library indeed as also mentioned by other users. The solution for me was to explicitly add Webpack to `package.json`, but not to the latest version but the latest 4.x version `4.47.0`.

```
$ npm install --save-dev webpack@4
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if that class is found in that path in webpack source code inside of node_modules. I had to install a previous version of webpack due to one of my dependencies required it

Answer (score -1):

Running into this issue as well in one of my old Vue Projects. Just use yarn

In your project folder do:

```
npm install -g yarn
rm -rf node-modules
unlink package-lock.json
yarn install
yarn start
```